# Chart in Powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-canvas

[image]I have a list that has a choice field that shows 'Deployed', 'Disposed' and 'Used'which indicated to each type of model laptop. How can I implement the chart within this two category which is status and type of model count together.

Comment: You may refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/use-line-pie-bar-chart to build a chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Items property of pie chart as shown below:

```
AddColumns(GroupBy(AddColumns('Task10/27',"ChoiceNew",Choice.Value),"ChoiceNew","GroupData"),"CountbyChoice",CountRows(GroupData))
```

[image]

Or like this:

```
  Table(
    {Col: "Disposed", Value: CountRows(Filter('Task10/27', Choice.Value = "Disposed"))
    },
    {Col: "Deployed", Value: CountRows(Filter('Task10/27', Choice.Value = "Deployed"))
    },
    {Col: "Used", Value: CountRows(Filter('Task10/27', Choice.Value = "Used"))
    }
)
```

[image]

My list:

[image]